# How do I remove shower handle to change stem?

Tags: plumbing, shower

It’s an old Price Pfister 3 handle shower system. The shower leaks cold water when it’s turned off.

I watched some videos and now I can’t  get past the first step, pulling off the handle.

I removed the screw. 
Soaked the handle in white vinegar with a plastic bag and rubber band. 
Wiggles it. Wiggles it some more. 
Nothing.

Could there be anything else holding on this handle? Is there some experienced move to reduce the pressure like turning the handle all the way open before removing?[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the screw you removed was behind the plastic/metal cap on the front of the handle. That handle has probably been on there since you were born and will have to be worked off. What has worked for me in the past is sliding a wrench behind the handle, over that chrome sleeve and tapping the back of the handle to try and move it forward. Continue to also move the handle back and forth. If all this fails, you'll probably have to get a small wheel puller to do the job.  Good luck